# Post to wall with a choice of thumbnails Javascript SKD

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using this code:

```
function postProductToFB(url) {
    // calling the API ... 
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: url,
        // values commented out can be added in specifically if required
        //picture: '-pre-filled image',
        //name: 'pre-filled title',
        //caption: 'pre-filled caption',
        //description: 'pre-filled description',
        to: 'page ID',
        from: 'page ID'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    };

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
};
```

To post products on my own wall from links on my website.

I have deliberately left the majority of parameters blank (commented out) so that Facebook can automatically scrape them from my web pages.

However, it often chooses the "wrong" thumbnail to display.

Is there any way that I can get it to show the choice of images it finds on the page as if I were pasting the URL into my Status Update field?

**EDIT, for clarification**

This is what happens when I post the URL directly into Facebook via a Status or Link update
[image]

Whereas:

This is what I get if I post using the JS SDK and the code above.

[image]

In this particular instance, it has chosen the correct image, but you can see from the top screenshot that there are actually 4 images to chose from. Each of these four images is explicitly coded into the `Head` of the document using `<meta name="" property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL">` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook relys on Open Graph tags to graph pictures from a website.  If no tags are present facebook loads all images on the pages for user to choose from.

refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Yeh, I understand that, but using the post-to-wall code above, it doesn't. I have specifically coded OG tags for each page, and have also tried it without. When pasting a URL directly into a status update, FB gives me the option to choose a thumbnail, either from images it has "found" by scraping the page, or from the specific OG tags if present, but by using the JS code above, it doesn't give me an option to choose from the thumbnails it finds.

Comment: once you add new or make changes to your meta tags you have to as an admin of the app run the url through the url linter to make facebook crawl the page.  Or you have to wait 24/48 hours for facebook to auto crawl the page. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I know, but again, that's not the problem! The problem is that the dialogue box generated by code above doesn't give me any choice as to which thumbnail is displayed with the post.

Comment: og:image is how you choose the image.     
 <meta property="og:image" content="your image url"/>

Comment: I've added some screenshots to the question for clarification of the issue

Comment: if you do not use the og:image tag, facebook will grab from what ever images it finds on the page that are above a certain width-height.  If you want to keep the choice of pics, just add some pics to your page and hide them in a div tag just under the body.  Make sure to add alt tags to them too.

Comment: there is no other way to do what you wish,  facebook does not have options for multible images that we can control.

Comment: Oh, that's annoying. OK, I guess I have to make my own method then.